# Spelling correction in comment everywhere privilege page

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, privileges, spelling

In each site's [Comment Everywhere - Privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) page, under **How do I comment?** section the description is starting as "Click the `add comment` link under each post....."

But actually in the posts `add a comment` is exists under the each question/answer. Hope this is a spelling mistake, need to be correct.

Screen shot for reference:

> [image: Should be add a comment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just updated the help center article to correct this.

Comment: 7 minutes. Has there been a faster fix?