# Spelling correction in Tour page

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, spelling, tour

In each site's [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page (except MSE) under **Improve posts by editing or commenting** section the image describes about how to use comments.

In that the content is as `add comment` but actually in the posts `add a comment` is exists under the each question/answer. Hope this is a spelling mistake, need to be correct.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Need to change "add comment" to "add a comment"]

<sup>Ref: Same kind of issue was [raised and fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274494/312043) for privilege page</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, looks like this bit wasn't kept consistent with the rest of the site (it lives in its own view, as it is something that just mimics the look of a post and isn't supposed to work like one otherwise).

With you in the next build.

Comment: This has been fixed in the SO version:`rev 2016.2.26.3299 `

Comment: Just I noticed, the change is not reflected in the Stack Exchange [Tour](http://stackexchange.com/tour) page

Comment: Forgot that se.com had a separate tour page. Fixed.

Comment: Verified, fixed on SE `2016.3.16.5806` version.